# Convert Timestamp to Date in excel

Tags: sql, excel, date, timestamp, hex

I got data from server to do some power bi job but the date format like timestamp and can't convert it to decimal or to date

0x00000000079A367B

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, but sql server timestamp datatype has no connection to date and/or time

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> In `SQL Server`; a timestamp column is automatically updated whenever a row is updated, and the value is monotonically increasing in the database. There is absolutely no relation to date and time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/238819/purpose-to-use-timestamp-datatype-in-sql-server.html

But you can cast this hexadecimal value to a `bigint` value as the following:

```
SELECT CAST (0x00000000079A367B AS BIGINT); --output is 127547003

or 

SELECT CAST (your_column AS BIGINT) as Num From Your_Table
```

Check this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06267146b8b3889a29db5091bcc83c3d).